# What's the Karabiner keycode for exclamation mark (!)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keycode, colemak

I'm trying to switch the keys '1' and '!' with Karabiner, but i cannot find the key code for the exclamation mark anywhere. Is it not possible?

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as '!', think of it as shift + 1.

Answer (score 1):

As far a I understand there is no unique keycode for !. Instead it is only output when the system receives Shift_R + 1.

From my own Karabiner file. Using Option H to output !.

```
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::H,
        ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
        KeyCode::KEY_1, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
    </autogen>
```